# Seg fault sending MPI derived types with allocatable arrays in fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi, derived-types

I am having troubles with a Fortran program where the master task sends an array of structs which has an allocatable array to the slaves. The slaves receive the array and print it successfully, however, after that the program crashes. GDB debugger shows the message below

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x2) at malloc.c:2931`

Certainly, I am missing something. Here is my code

```
program test_type  

use mpi

implicit none

type mytype
real,allocatable::x(:)
integer::a
end type mytype

type(mytype),allocatable::y(:)
integer::n,i,ierr,myid,ntasks,status
integer :: datatype0, ntasktype, oldtypes(2), blockcounts(2) 
integer, allocatable :: oldtypes2(:), blockcounts2(:), datatype(:)
integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: offsets(2)
integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND), allocatable :: offsets2(:)
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,ntasks,ierr)

n=2
allocate(y(ntasks))
allocate(oldtypes2(ntasks), blockcounts2(ntasks))
allocate(offsets2(ntasks), datatype(ntasks))
do i=1,ntasks
 allocate(y(i)%x(n))
 y(i)%x=0.
 y(i)%a=80
enddo

    if(myid==0)then
     do i=1,ntasks
      call random_number(y(i)%x)
      y(i)%a=myid
      write(0,*) "y(",i,") in process", myid, y(i)%x, y(i)%a
     enddo
    endif

   ! (1) Create a separate structure datatype for each record
   do i=1,ntasks
    call mpi_get_address(y(i)%x,offsets(1),ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(y(i)%a,offsets(2),ierr)
    offsets=offsets-offsets(1)

    oldtypes=(/ mpi_real,mpi_integer /)
    blockcounts=(/ n,1 /)

    call mpi_type_create_struct(2,blockcounts,offsets,oldtypes,datatype(i),ierr) 
   end do

   ! (2) Create a structure of structures that describes the whole array
   do i=1,ntasks
    call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(     y(i)%x, offsets2(i), ierr)
   enddo
   offsets2 = offsets2 - offsets2(1)
   do i=1,ntasks
    oldtypes2(i)=datatype(i)
    blockcounts2(i)=1
   enddo
   call mpi_type_create_struct(ntasks,blockcounts2,offsets2,oldtypes2,ntasktype,ierr) 
  call mpi_type_commit(ntasktype, ierr)

  ! (2.1) Free the intermediate datatypes
  do i=1,ntasks
   call MPI_TYPE_FREE(datatype(i), ierr)
  enddo

 ! (3) Send the array
 if(myid==0) then   
  do i=1,ntasks-1 
   call MPI_SEND(y(1)%x, 1, ntasktype, &
            i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  enddo
  do i=1,ntasks-1 
   write(0,*) "sent", y(i)%x,y(i)%a
  enddo
else
 call MPI_RECV(y(1)%x,1, ntasktype, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
 do i=1,ntasks
  write(0,*) "task(",myid,") received", i,y(i)%x,y(i)%a
 enddo
end if

deallocate(y)
deallocate(oldtypes2, blockcounts2)
deallocate(offsets2,datatype)
call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program
```

Comment: Could you make a shorter testable version of your code in that the same error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man MPI_Recv`

```
Fortran Syntax
       USE MPI
       ! or the older form: INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
       MPI_RECV(BUF, COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM, STATUS, IERROR)
            <type>    BUF(*)
            INTEGER   COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM
            INTEGER   STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), IERROR
```

Your issue is a memory corruption on non zero ranks, because you declared

```
integer :: status
```

instead of

```
integer :: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
```

As a side note, you can simplify your code by directly creating a derived datatypes with `2*ntasks` elements, and then use `MPI_BOTTOM` as both send and receive buffer.

If you really want to manipulate offsets, you should use `MPI_Aint_diff()` instead of the `-` operator.

**[EDIT]** Here is a revamped/simplified version that uses `MPI_BOTTOM`

```
program test_type  

use mpi

implicit none

type mytype
real,allocatable::x(:)
integer::a
end type mytype

type(mytype),allocatable::y(:)
integer::n,i,ierr,myid,ntasks,status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer :: ntasktype
integer, allocatable :: oldtypes(:), blockcounts(:)
integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND), allocatable :: offsets(:)

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,ntasks,ierr)

n=2
allocate(y(ntasks))
allocate(oldtypes(2*ntasks), blockcounts(2*ntasks))
allocate(offsets(2*ntasks))
do i=1,ntasks
 allocate(y(i)%x(n))
 y(i)%x=0.
 y(i)%a=80
enddo

if(myid==0)then
  do i=1,ntasks
    call random_number(y(i)%x)
    y(i)%a=myid
    write(0,*) "y(",i,") in process", myid, y(i)%x, y(i)%a
   enddo
endif

do i=1,ntasks
  call mpi_get_address(y(i)%x,offsets(2*i-1),ierr)
  call mpi_get_address(y(i)%a,offsets(2*i  ),ierr)

  oldtypes(2*i-1) = mpi_real
  oldtypes(2*i  ) = mpi_integer

  blockcounts(2*i-1) = n
  blockcounts(2*i  ) = 1
end do

call mpi_type_create_struct(2*ntasks,blockcounts,offsets,oldtypes,ntasktype,ierr) 
call mpi_type_commit(ntasktype, ierr)

! (3) Send the array
if(myid==0) then   
  do i=1,ntasks-1 
    call MPI_SEND(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, ntasktype, &
                  i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  enddo
  do i=1,ntasks-1 
   write(0,*) "sent", y(i)%x,y(i)%a
  enddo
else
  call MPI_RECV(MPI_BOTTOM,1, ntasktype, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
  do i=1,ntasks
    write(0,*) "task(",myid,") received", i,y(i)%x,y(i)%a
  enddo
end if

do i=1, ntasks
  deallocate(y(i)%x)
enddo
deallocate(y)
deallocate(oldtypes, blockcounts)
deallocate(offsets)

call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a silly mistake. Actually, I was asking myself if there is a way to simplify the code as the array x (for each y) will maintain the same size. @Gilles Could you give me a little more detail about the option you referred in your note?

Comment: @Pepito I edited my answer and added my revamped/simplified version

Comment: Wow, it became much simpler. I could notice you are one of the main contributors to the Open MPI mailing lists. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question :).